# error in activity class regarding AnimationListener

Tags: android, animation, listener

I am following the Sams Teach Yourself Android Applications workbook and have filled in the following for QuizSplashActivity class, as instructed in the book. However, I get an error in the code that I have put in bold ****, where it says `AnimationListener()`:

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTopTitle);
Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
logo1.startAnimation(fade1);

TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBottomTitle);
Animation fade3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
logo2.startAnimation(fade3);

Animation spinin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
    row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
fade2.setAnimationListener(new **AnimationListener()** {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
        QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    // stop the animation
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTopTitle);
    logo1.clearAnimation();

    TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBottomTitle);
    logo2.clearAnimation();

    // ... stop other animations

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        row.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

}

The error is:

> "`The type new Animation.AnimationListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Animation.AnimationListener.onAnimationStart(Animation`)".

The book does not mention anything about this and just wondered if someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Moses

Answer (score 2):

`AnimationListener` is an interface. That means that when you put it in your code, you have to implement all the methods.
As seen in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html), there are three methods:

```
onAnimationStart(Animation a)
onAnimationEnd(Animation a)
onAnimationRepeat(Animation a)
```

You have only implemented one: `onAnimationEnd`.
You have to implement the others, even if you put nothing in them.

Here would be your revised code:

```
fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
        QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) { }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) { }

});
```

Note the new methods in the class.

I hope this helped!